# How to simiulate a JSON call from an HTTP GET Call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, json

At this moment I am calling my index view in one of two ways. Using the normal http view and serializing it JSON.  In order to test it I am using the code below, and it works.  I want to get it with a http get call. Like (http://localhost/article,json or something similar.  Any ideas.

```
$.getJSON("/Article", function(json) {
  $.each(json, function(i, article) {
    alert(article.title);
  });
});
```

At this moment the index called to /article is being differentiated with the following IsAjaxRequest method.  but my real question is if I am able to get around the .getJSON method in JQuery to test the following code.

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
  return Json(articles);
} else {
  return View(articles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reuse the same action method for both a full GET (the page load) and an AJAX call (via getJSON), you'll run into issues because each action method should have a unique name.  Otherwise, the MVC engine can't tell which action method should be called when a particular Url is requested.

You'll need two separate actions: one for the full page load that returns a ViewResult and the other for the AJAX call that returns a JsonResult.  If you need the Urls for these actions to look the same, you can also play around with mapped routes that direct to different action methods.

So, how about:

/Article/Index
  Maps to the default Index action (full page load)

/Article/Refresh
  Maps to the Refresh action (asynchronous JSON call)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but can't you make an optional parameter called "format", so that you pass in ?format=json to switch what reply type you get back?

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest() || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(format) && format.Equals("json"))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering how to test your action and you're talking about doing automated testing, see if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970198/how-to-mock-the-request-on-controller-in-asp-net-mvc) answers your question.