# How to unit test this .net MVC function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have this function and unit test.

**ProfileController Code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
  var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Profile", new { id = 0 });
  return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
}
```

**unit test code**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDetailsViewData()
{
    var controller = new ProfileController(_Profile); 

    var result = controller.Edit(1) as ViewResult;
    var profile = (VIEWMODELS.Customer.Profile)result.ViewData.Model;
    Assert.AreEqual("Testor", profile.cardName);
}
```

i would like to test this function and this function will redirect to index page and return ViewPage with data. But the problem is when i run this unit test code i got Null exception at this line ,because of the Request is NULL

```
var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Profile", new { id = 0 });
```

so may i know how could i test this?

**Updated with Moq function**
After further reading and get some sample code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970198/how-to-mock-the-request-on-controller-in-asp-net-mvc) it seem request able to filled with value but now the RequestContext is NULL, anyone can point me to right place for me to study?

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestDetailsViewData()
        {
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(); 
            request.SetupGet(x => x.Headers).Returns(
                new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection {
                {"X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"}
            });

            var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
            //context.SetupGet(x => x.Request.RequestContext ).Returns(request.Object.RequestContext);

            var controller = new ProfileController(_Profile);
            controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
            controller.Request.RequestContext = context.Object.Request.RequestContext;
            var result = controller.Edit(1) as ViewResult;
            var profile = (VIEWMODELS.Customer.Profile)result.ViewData.Model;
            Assert.AreEqual("testor", profile.cardName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the request is not defined in Test method.I think you have to use visual studio fakes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Comment: thanks for your suggested link, it would be helpful if you could provide sample code.