# How to mock the Request for ASP.Net WebForm Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mstest

I have following asp.net Page `Contact` and having `TestHandlerDemoClass` which is having one method I want to write a unit test case for that method but when I tried it using `MSTest project` it throws exception like 
`Request not available in this context`

```
public partial class Contact : Page
    {

    }
 public class TestHandlerDemoClass
    {
 public void MyTestMethod(Page mypage)
        {
       string id= mypage.Request["EntityId"]

//here I'm not getting Request inside mypage
```

My Test Project code -

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void NullCheck()
        {
            try
            {
                Contact contactPage = new Contact();
                TestHandlerDemoClass mydemo = new TestHandlerDemoClass();
                mydemo.MyTestMethod(contactPage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(ex.Message, "Id not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

here in above ex I got message like `{"Request is not available in this context"}`

I 'm just trying to write unit test cases for method `

```
public void MyTestMethod(Page mypage)
```

which takes `Page mypage` as parameter.

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mocking your `Contact` class the test will pass, the problem is most of the unit testing tools doesn't allow to mock a Non-virtual Class.
im using [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com) where its possible to mock almost any type of Object without changing your code, and its realy esay to use.

for example:

```
  [TestMethod]
        public void NullCheck()
        {
            try
            {
                var contactPage = Isolate.Fake.Instance<Contact>();
                TestHandlerDemoClass t = new TestHandlerDemoClass();
                t.MyTestMethod(contactPage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(ex.Message, "Id not found");
            }
        }
```

Comment: how and where it will assign a request value `EntityId`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in unit testing, but I think you should **pass a mock object** like is answered here: [How to mock the Request on Controller in ASP.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970198/how-to-mock-the-request-on-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I got your point thanks but instead of mock it would be more simpler if I got to know how to pass a page request from unit test method

Comment: An [HttpRequest object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) is something quite complicated, that is build starting from what is sent by a client able to send http request (often, a browser). I doubt you can find something simpler than a mock

Comment: how to mock for asp.net instead of controller as my method is having Page as input?