# Unit testing Mock request object MVC .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, unit-testing

Unit testing on MVC vb.net project. One of the action method in my controller, I was getting an error on `Request.Params["FieldName"]`

In this case, how to mock: `Request.Params["FieldName"]` in unit test method? Prefer VB.net, and c# is accepted too.

```
    Dim httpRequest = New Mock(Of System.Web.HttpRequestBase)()
    Dim httpContext = New Mock(Of System.Web.HttpContextBase)()

    Dim parameters As New NameValueCollection()
    parameters("YourField") = "testField"

    httpRequest.Setup(Function(x) x.Params).Returns(parameters)
    httpContext.Setup(Function(x) x.Request).Returns(httpRequest.[Object])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock the Request on Controller in ASP.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970198/how-to-mock-the-request-on-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mock the request and the context. In the request, you need to mock the `Params["YourField"]` as well but the problem is that this indexer is not `virtual` so you will not be able to mock it. Instead you can mock `Get` method. Here is how to do so with [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4):

```
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
// We are mocking the Get method
request.Setup(x => x.Params.Get("FieldName")).Returns("whatever...");

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
```

In your code, you will need to use `Get` instead of the indexer (You cannot use `Params[""]`).

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thanks CodingYoshi. But I got a syntax error in VB, do you know why? https://www.screencast.com/t/LUlQKnd7JLTN

Comment: @Julia That is my fault. It should be `Setup` not, `SetupGet`...probably auto-correct on my phone. I have edited and fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I got the correct syntax, but I got another runtime error, do you know the reason? https://www.screencast.com/t/XiZIfO4Xam

Comment: @Julia See my edit please.

Comment: IIt has no exception now, but in my controller method, I need to request parameter value:

Comment: Public Function SaveReord()

            Dim FieldNo As Integer

            FieldNo = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params("FieldName"))
 ...
 End Function

Comment: That is, I couldn't get Request.Params value there.

Comment: @julia read my answer carefully please. You cannot just copy paste my code and if it does not work, message me. You need to read your code, the error and reread the answer before you message me. You cannot use `Request.Params("FieldName")` as I explained in the answer. Use `Get("FieldName")` instead.

Comment: It's fixed by using NameValueCollection property to be able to get request params. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @julia just to confirm: you used `Request.Params.Get("FieldName")` in your code, right?

Comment: see my edit above, I can get Request.Params("FieldName") value by using NameValueCollection in HttpRequest setup.